# Randomness without Cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random

It might sound weird but up until now in my studies the randomness was assigned to a Cumulative distribution function which is a deterministic mapping (for discrete and continuous) random variables.

My question is can we go a little more further ? i.e. are there random phenomenon (maybe from physics or economy or constructed by maths) to which it is proven that we cannot assign a (deterministic) Cumulative distribution function ?
Thank you for your answer,

Comment: The CDF exists for any random variable.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820145/true-random-number-set

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @fesman's comment, a random variable $X$ is a measurable function on a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathbb P)$. We define for any such $X$ the cumulative distribution function $F_X:(-\infty,\infty)\to[0,1]$ by
$$
F_X(x) := \mathbb P(X\leqslant x), 
$$
or to be more explicit,
$$
F_X(x) := \mathbb P(\{\omega\in\Omega : X(\omega)\leqslant x).
$$
We cannot define a "random phenomenon" without a distribution function. It is more likely that the "randomness" in your studies did not consist of rigorous probability theory.

Comment: about the 'cannot define', is the following relevant? '[Every function with these four properties is a CDF, i.e., for every such function, a random variable can be defined such that the function is the cumulative distribution function of that random variable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)'

Comment: @BCLC I don't think you're understanding the question being asked. It is not whether one can define such a function without the concept of randomness, but instead whether one can rigorously define "randomness" without e.g. such a function.

Comment: Math1000 not for the question specifically, i mean in general. oh wait i mean 'related' not 'relevant'. i think that was where i confusing