# An algorithm for enumerating subsequences of all infinite binary sequences?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, algorithmic-randomness

We consider that an infinite binary sequence $s$ is **not** random in the sense of **Martin-Löf**.

For all the $s$ sequences which respect this constraint, is it possible to build an algorithm which can enumerate (in a set of indices $I$) all the positions of the numbers **1** in the sequence $s$ ?

If this is the case, can we consider that all languages which are in the arithmetical hierarchy, **excluding those in $\Delta$1**, refer to an infinite binary sequence considered **random by Martin-Löf**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not at all.

Let $f$ be any binary sequence whatsoever and let $g(2n)=f(n), g(2n+1)=0$. Then $g$ is not Martin-Lof random but $\{x:g(x)=1\}$ is exactly as complicated as $\{x:f(x)=1\}$. Non-randomness is *not* a simplicity condition.

Or, put another way, **complexity does not imply randomness**. *(For an extreme type of example of highly-complex but highly-nonrandom sequences, consider [genericity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820145/true-random-number-set/3820229#3820229).)*

Comment: Thank you very much, it's much clearer !